# SQL SELECT with grouping

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select last record from each conversation between 2 users

My table:

```
id | sender_id | recipient_id | message
1     2           3              msg_1 
2     3           2              msg_2
4     2           3              msg_4
5     2           3              msg_5
7     4           3              msg_7
8     3           4              msg_8
```

After select it should find this records

```
id | sender_id | recipient_id | message 
5     2           3              msg_5
8     3           4              msg_8
```

Comment: The problem would be esier to solve if you added timestamp to every row.

Comment: My mistake, there should be 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   id = ( SELECT   MAX(id)
           FROM     mytable
           WHERE    ( sender_id = m.sender_Id
                      OR recipient_id = m.sender_id
                    )
                    AND ( recipient_id = m.recipient_Id
                          OR sender_id = m.recipient_id
                        )
         )
```

Comment: sorry, moving too fast!  I tested this version